# Postgres/PostGIS calculate area of Polygon in Square Miles

Tags: postgis, postgresql, geometry

Polygon in Postgres/PostGIS database. It has the spatial reference 4269 which is in degrees.

I know there is a ST_Area() to calculate it. 
this is my query to select the areas in the SRID units.

```
select st_area(geom) from counties;
```

I want to calculate the area in Square Miles and insert a column named Area with the correct Square Mileage for each county

*I am a new to SQL and Postgres

Answer (score 16, accepted):

ST_Area will use the units in your coordinate system, which as you say are degrees. So you have two options:

- transform your geometries to a coordinate system that uses feet or meters
- cast your geometries as geographies. ST_Area will then perform the calculation in meters.

You then need to convert from square feet or square meters to square miles.

Your query would look something like this

```
ALTER TABLE counties ADD COLUMN area real;
UPDATE counties SET area = ST_Area(geom::geography) / 1609.34^2
```

Comment: awesome I will give this a try

Comment: Saved a day. Thanks heaps @amball!